# Build fails because can't copy DLL after I killed vhost.exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I ran a project with debug from VS2015.

I realised the project would run for hours, and so I used Taskmanager to kill Project.vhost.exe.

Now when I try to build I get an error because it can't delete several DLLs in bin/debug.

When I look at these DLLs with explorer I see I have no permissions to even view them (I am admin).

How can I get these file accessible again?

Cleaning solution does NOT work as it can't delete these files.

Comment: Sometimes you even though you can't remove it from windows explorer you can by command line. Try `rm -rf bin\`

Answer (score 0):

Reboot the machine, then clean, then rebuild. It should be fine.

Something has the file open, but it's going to be faster to reboot than try to figure out what it is.

Comment: Yes. I thought that too. But I looked for it with Resource Monitor. I don't think anything has it.

Comment: Either something has the file open or your filesystem is damaged.

Comment: It's also possible that you ran VS under a different account at some point and your current account really doesn't have access to the files.

Comment: It is that. I can't get access back though - so can't delete the file

Comment: If the machine is on a domain, you can ask a domain admin to delete the folder for you. You could also copy the solution and all the source files/config files to a new directory and work from there.